# Reinstall windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem on my pc which is running Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit. My hard drive is a 320gb one which has no partitions at present - just the OS and all data files on the one disk partition. Obviously reinstalling W7 from fresh is a pain in the a*** and is the very, very last resort, with all the reinstalling programs etc that follows!

So, what I want to ask is whether there is a way of dividing my existing hard drive into two partitions (keeping the existing OS on Partition A), then doing a clean and separate install of W7 into a new partition B, and booting to that OS so I can see if my problems go away by running off the new install. Then, if it works, I would then delete first OS and backup all files to new partition, then change disk back to being a single partition.

Hope you see what I am getting at. Any guidance (in very non-tech terms please!) will be appreciated.

Comment: Laptop? If desktop get/install a 2nd hd instead of messing with partitions. If you start editing partitions you SHOULD backup everything first onto another hd anyways, instead install  a 2nd hd to install Win7 clean or use it for backup. INstall on 2nd hd would be best. If its a latop, then backup everything externally

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink your volume by going to computer management.
this link is useful http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/02/how-to-shrink-the-primary-c-partition-in-windows-vista-windows-7/

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. It would be helpful to include more information in your answer, including the steps to complete your answer.

Comment: ok, i edited the answer

Comment: Links can break over time so it's useful to include a summary or quote sections (use " button to quote the text). You don't have to write a novel but more detailed answers are more likely to get up voted. Thanks.

Comment: thnx for suggesting, keep into account next time